Undefined reference to clFFT
I am trying to use clFFT
so I could calculate FFT on GPU
I use Msys2 MinGW64 (mingw-w64-x86_64) and Cmake
and OpenCL works fine for me (I use AMD GPU) and installed OpenCL with pacman: pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-opencl-clhpp)
I was trying to run a small clFFT example
#include <stdlib.h>

/* No need to explicitely include the OpenCL headers */
#define CL_USE_DEPRECATED_OPENCL_1_2_APIS
#include <clFFT.h>

int main( void )
{
    cl_int err;
    cl_platform_id platform = 0;
    cl_device_id device = 0;
    cl_context_properties props[3] = { CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, 0, 0 };
    cl_context ctx = 0;
    cl_command_queue queue = 0;
    cl_mem bufX;
    float *X;
    cl_event event = NULL;
    int ret = 0;
    size_t N = 16;

    /* FFT library realted declarations */
    clfftPlanHandle planHandle;
    clfftDim dim = CLFFT_1D;
    size_t clLengths[1] = {N};

    /* Setup OpenCL environment. */
    err = clGetPlatformIDs( 1, &platform, NULL );
    err = clGetDeviceIDs( platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &device, NULL );

    props[1] = (cl_context_properties)platform;
    ctx = clCreateContext( props, 1, &device, NULL, NULL, &err );
    queue = clCreateCommandQueue( ctx, device, 0, &err );

    /* Setup clFFT. */
    clfftSetupData fftSetup;
    err = clfftInitSetupData(&fftSetup);
    err = clfftSetup(&fftSetup);

    /* Allocate host & initialize data. */
    /* Only allocation shown for simplicity. */
    X = (float *)malloc(N * 2 * sizeof(*X));

    /* Prepare OpenCL memory objects and place data inside them. */
    bufX = clCreateBuffer( ctx, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, N * 2 * sizeof(*X), NULL, &err );

    err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer( queue, bufX, CL_TRUE, 0,
                                N * 2 * sizeof( *X ), X, 0, NULL, NULL );

    /* Create a default plan for a complex FFT. */
    err = clfftCreateDefaultPlan(&planHandle, ctx, dim, clLengths);

    /* Set plan parameters. */
    err = clfftSetPlanPrecision(planHandle, CLFFT_SINGLE);
    err = clfftSetLayout(planHandle, CLFFT_COMPLEX_INTERLEAVED, CLFFT_COMPLEX_INTERLEAVED);
    err = clfftSetResultLocation(planHandle, CLFFT_INPLACE);

    /* Bake the plan. */
    err = clfftBakePlan(planHandle, 1, &queue, NULL, NULL);

    /* Execute the plan. */
    err = clfftEnqueueTransform(planHandle, CLFFT_FORWARD, 1, &queue, 0, NULL, NULL, &bufX, NULL, NULL);

    /* Wait for calculations to be finished. */
    err = clFinish(queue);

    /* Fetch results of calculations. */
    err = clEnqueueReadBuffer( queue, bufX, CL_TRUE, 0, N * 2 * sizeof( *X ), X, 0, NULL, NULL );

    /* Release OpenCL memory objects. */
    clReleaseMemObject( bufX );

    free(X);

    /* Release the plan. */
    err = clfftDestroyPlan( &planHandle );

    /* Release clFFT library. */
    clfftTeardown( );

    /* Release OpenCL working objects. */
    clReleaseCommandQueue( queue );
    clReleaseContext( ctx );

    return ret;
}

My CMakeLists.txt looks like
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(clFFT_demo)

#set( CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on )
#SET(CMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE ${CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE})

find_package(OpenCL REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCL_INCLUDE_DIR})

# clFFT
file(GLOB CLFFT_SRC external/clfft/*.cpp)
file(GLOB CLFFT_SRC external/clfft/*.c)
add_library(clFFT STATIC ${CLFFT_SRC})
target_include_directories(clFFT PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/external/clfft/include)

include_directories(include)

add_executable(clFFT_demo main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(clFFT_demo clFFT OpenCL::OpenCL)
target_compile_features(clFFT_demo PRIVATE cxx_range_for cxx_auto_type)

# OpenCL HelloWorld
add_executable(OpenCL_demo OpenCLDemo.cpp)
target_link_libraries(OpenCL_demo OpenCL::OpenCL)
target_compile_features(OpenCL_demo PRIVATE cxx_range_for cxx_auto_type)

#Copy OpenCL Kernels into build dir
file(GLOB KERNELS kernels/*.cl)
foreach(CurrentKernel IN LISTS KERNELS)
    cmake_path(GET CurrentKernel FILENAME FileName)
    add_custom_command(
            TARGET OpenCL_demo PRE_BUILD
            COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different ${CurrentKernel} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/kernels/${FileName}
            COMMENT "Copying kernel: ${CurrenKernel}")
endforeach()

since I wanted to staticly link and include clFFT inside my executable I copied the library to external folder and add aproproate includes and libraries
the library (clFFT) appears to build fine (since I do get libclFFT.a in my build directory
but for some reason all the functions appears to still be unknown to the linker since I get thie errors
[100%] Linking CXX executable clFFT_demo.exe
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\clFFT_demo.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): in function `main':
D:/stuff/clFFTTest/main.cpp:37: undefined reference to `clfftSetup'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:/stuff/clFFTTest/main.cpp:50: undefined reference to `clfftCreateDefaultPlan'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:/stuff/clFFTTest/main.cpp:53: undefined reference to `clfftSetPlanPrecision'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:/stuff/clFFTTest/main.cpp:54: undefined reference to `clfftSetLayout'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:/stuff/clFFTTest/main.cpp:55: undefined reference to `clfftSetResultLocation'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:/stuff/clFFTTest/main.cpp:58: undefined reference to `clfftBakePlan'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:/stuff/clFFTTest/main.cpp:61: undefined reference to `clfftEnqueueTransform'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:/stuff/clFFTTest/main.cpp:75: undefined reference to `clfftDestroyPlan'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:/stuff/clFFTTest/main.cpp:78: undefined reference to `clfftTeardown'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\clFFT_demo.dir\build.make:97: clFFT_demo.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:138: CMakeFiles/clFFT_demo.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:145: CMakeFiles/clFFT_demo.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:149: clFFT_demo] Error 2

I am not sure what to do now, how do I include clFFT so linker will find it properly (compiler compiles everything fine so includes are properly found, its just that linker complains)
Here is my whole example if anyone wants to try it: clFFT
Thanks for Anwsering and Best Regards

I managed to fix it
Download clFFT put it inside third_party
put this inside CmakeList.txt
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/third_party/clFFT/src)
include_directories( ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/third_party/clFFT/src/include )
include_directories( ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/third_party/clFFT/src/include )

file(GLOB CLFFTDLL ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/third_party/clFFT/src/staging/*.dll)
foreach(CurrentFile IN LISTS CLFFTDLL)
    cmake_path(GET CurrentFile FILENAME FileName)
    add_custom_command(
            TARGET OceanFFT PRE_BUILD
            COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different ${CurrentFile} ${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/${FileName}
            COMMENT "Copying ${FileName}" )
endforeach()

There is only one problem that stays: DLL won't copy on first build, I have to build the executable again for dll to be copied automaticly
